# Регулярные выражения и знак "^"

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Почему не работает такое регулярное выражение:

```
$content = "privetpri";
if(preg_match("/(^privet).*/is", $content)) { die('1'); } else die('0');
```

По идее, оно должно показывать `0`, если в выражении присутствует `"privet"` и `1`, если отсутствует. Но в чём ошибка, почему регулярка работает неправильно?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Всё правильно работает . Если совпадение найдено - 1, иначе - 0